# Global variable usage in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have set 3 global variables as below in a file FILE1:

```
set VAR1    2   
set VAR2    3   
set VAR3    4
```

Now I want to use these 3 variables in another file FILE2 in iterative way:

Means, something like this:

```
for {set a 1} {$a < 4} {incr a} {
    $::VAR$a
}
```

where VAR$a - should be incremented each time to VAR1,VAR2,VAR3 etc...

But if I try like this using the global variable I get error in tcl

Any better solution for this?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing *arrays* are for.

Answer (score 2):

Either make your meaning clearer to the interpreter

```
set ::VAR$a
```

(you are aware that this is just getting the variable's value without doing anything with the value, that is, a pointless operation, right?)

Or use an array, which is basically a two-part variable name:

```
set ::VAR($a)
```

in which case you need to initialize as an array:

```
set VAR(1) 2
```

etc, or

```
array set VAR {1 2 2 3 3 4}
```

The reason why `$::VAR$a` doesn't always work is AFAICT that the variable substitution becomes ambiguous. Given these definitions:

```
set foobar 1
set a foo
set b bar
```

what should `$a$b` substitute into? To avoid ambiguity, the substitution rules are kept simple: the first substitution stops before the second dollar sign, and the whole expression evaluates to the string `foobar`. How about `$$a$b` to substitute the value of `foobar`, then? No, a dollar-sign followed directly by a character that can't be a part of a variable name means that the first dollar sign becomes just a dollar sign: you get `$foobar`. The best way to handle this is to reduce the levels of substitution using the `set` command to get a value: `set $a$b`. Bottom line: variable substitution using `$` does not always work well, but the `set` always does the job.

Documentation:
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)